# Calculate distance between GPS points by coordinates

Tags: php, gps, coordinates, distance, haversine

I'm having some trouble computing the distance between two GPS points by their coordinates.

```
point a
x = 7,2562
y = 47,7434599999999

point b 
x = 7,21978
y = 47,73836
```

I used the Haversine formula as described [here](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#PHP). The result I get is 4.09 km.

However, locating those points on a map using a tool like [this](https://www.gps-coordinates.net/), I can measure a distance of [2.8 km](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/47.74346,+7.2562%09/47.73836,7.21978/@47.7410535,7.2299719,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d7.2562!2d47.74346!1m0)

Several other formulas I tried also return a result around 4 km.

Any ideas what I would be missing ?

Comment: Google maps tells the point is 4km apart.

Comment: Well, that's not what I see here:
https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/47.74346,+7.2562%09/47.73836,7.21978/@47.7410535,7.2299719,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d7.2562!2d47.74346!1m0

Comment: Ah, the problem is the order of the coordinates. (7, 47 not 47, 7)

Comment: Oh oh you are absolutely right... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Roland Starke in the comments, the problem was the order of the coordinates. (7, 47 not 47, 7)

Answer (score 0):

I think is because u are using the function in miles, in Kms you can use something like that:

```
    public static function distance(
        array $from,
        array $to
    ) {
        if (empty($from['lat']) || empty($to['lat'])) {
            return $to['distance'];
        }

        $latitude1  = (float) $from['lat'];
        $latitude2  = (float) $to['lat'];
        $longitude1 = (float) $from['lng'];
        $longitude2 = (float) $to['lng'];

        $theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2;
        $distance = (sin(deg2rad($latitude1)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude2)))
            + (cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)))
        ;
        $distance = acos($distance);
        $distance = rad2deg($distance);
        $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;
        $distance = (is_nan($distance)) ? 0 : $distance * 1.609344;

        return  $distance;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just tested your code and I get the same result as before: 4.09km.

Comment: Be carefull with numbers 47,73836 is not the same that 47.73836 (dot in numbers)